# Precedency of Postfix and prefix operator in C

Tags: c, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I am finding difficulty to understand how precedency works in the following case. Can anyone explain why the answer is different in below two printf functions?

```
int main()
{

    int a=10,b=20,c;
    c= a++ + ++a - --b - b-- + ++a;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    printf("%d",a++ + ++a - --b - b-- + ++a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not sure why every professor has to trouble students with these kinds of nonsense - which nobody uses in real code

Comment: This is a classic example of undefined behaviour. A waste of time trying to understand or explain.